# how to get a date in "YYYY-MM" format?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column with date format like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. I  need to convert this column to the `YYYY-MM` format. What do I need to do for this?
I tried use DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', date), it works but not that way I want to. For example, I have a date `2018-11-14T00:00:00.000Z` and when I apply DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', date_column), I get `2018-10-31T23:00:00.000Z`. I expected `2018-11-31T00:00:00.000` or `2018-11-011T00:00:00.000` or `2018-11`. Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that column is defined as `timestamp` or `timestamptz` (which it *really* should be) then you can use `to_char()` to [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) the output:

```
select to_char(the_timestamp_column, 'yyyy-mm')
from the_table;
```